# How to get a value from a JSON hash

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a jquery ajax call I get sent back some JSON from the server and want to use some of it in the success callback.  I pass in the data, but how do I get at a specific value (say "id")?

I tried this but I get undefined:

```
                      success   : function(data) {
                                    alert(data["id"]);
                                  },
```

Comment: Is your `dataType` set to `json`? If you `alert(data)` what comes out?

Comment: Yes set to json.  The alert gives all the data in json, just not sure how to get a single item.

Comment: @Cameron - What about `alert(typeof data)`?  You sure it's not giving back a string?

Comment: can you post the exact json string received?

Comment: you need to specify `dataType: json` in the $.ajax call.

Comment: looks like {"_id":"4c082cb21344600346000020","created_at":"2010-06-03T23:29:06+01:00"}

Comment: I had dataType: "JSON" in uppercase. Looks like that fixed it!
Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax request should look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "...",
  dataType: "json", 
  success: function(data){
    alert(data.id);
  });
```